GPS Location fails on some devices?
I have a net maui app that uses GPS to record the users location. It's important that the user can put away the phone while running the app and for this reason we prompt the user to allow GPS "always on" (which seems a bit overkill, "while using the app" would be better if I could be certain that the GPS continues to record as long as the app is running).
For most users, this works fine, but for some Android users the app stops recording when the user shuts off the screen to put the phone in her pocket. How can I make sure that all android users get this to work?
I'm using android platform implementation:
    public partial class LocationService : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationListener
    {
        LocationManager _locationManager;
        Intent _foregroundService;

        public partial void InitLocations()
        {
            var service = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            _locationManager = (LocationManager)service;

            _foregroundService = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ForegroundService));
            _foregroundService.SetAction(ForegroundService.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(_foregroundService);

            _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 100, 0.5f, this);
        }

        public void OnLocationChanged(Android.Locations.Location newLocation)
        {
            HandleNewLocation(new Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.Location()
            {
                Latitude = newLocation.Latitude,
                Longitude = newLocation.Longitude,
                Altitude = newLocation.Altitude,
                Accuracy = newLocation.Accuracy,
                Course = newLocation.Bearing,
                Speed = newLocation.Speed,
                Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(newLocation.Time)  
            });
        }

My AndroidManifest has:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />


Screen off is Doze mode. Unclear if you've screen: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Welcome to battery saving nightmare. Vendors can (and do) battery save optimization and they may override GPS tracking, and each vendor may implement something different. I think some popular apps have good documentation on how to do it with different versions and vendors. No benchmark/review will check accuracy, just battery life and performances, so it it a lost battle.

As a general idea I think this is good but for an app that requires constant GPS it should/must be possible to let the user allow the app to do it? On my s21 galaxy it prompts me that google maps is draining battery but I can still choose that I want to keep it alive.

Great link though for support cases!

Usually in battery optimization you will find setting to disable battery optimization which may include killing precise location on background apps. I think I found documents on OsmAnd+ app site or other logger (and I think it may depends on some heuristic of vendors to find if the app has legitimate reason for it, so logger may be whitelisted)
